# How to find in c++ STL in a specific manner?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, dictionary, stl

```
map< pair<int,int> , int > m ;
```

Here `pair.first` and `pair.second` are positive and `pair.second >= pair.first`.

I would like to find all iterator/s in map `m` such that for a given key. Key is an integer which lies between pairs e.g. key is 2 and pair is `[2,5]` and `[1,2]` etc.
e.g. `m[1,3] = 10 , m[3,5] = 6 , m[1,8] = 9 , m[7,8] = 15`  then when I search for `m.find(3)` then it would return iterator for `m[1,3]` , `m[1,8]` , `m[3,5]` .If there is no key then it would return `m.end()`.

Comment: You want to find keys where the search value `i` is between the two pair values?

Comment: Ok. It was hard to read that from your question.

Comment: Your example seems wrong. Do you mean you iterators to `m[1,3]` and `m[3,5]` instead of `m[2,3]`?

Comment: what does "+ve" mean?

Comment: what if keys are [1,3], [2,4], [3,5] and you search for 3, what should you find?

Comment: @Slava It would return all key since 3 is lies b/w all of them .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why* you want to do this, but these days Boost Interval Container library is pretty capable.

Assuming that you might have wanted to keep track of the *total* (sum) of mapped values for a specific point, you could simply apply a splitting **[Combining Style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html#boost_icl.introduction.interval_combining_styles)** to your input data and profit:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/559332112fb37d3a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/icl/split_interval_map.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

int main() {
    using Map  = icl::split_interval_map<int, int>;
    using Ival = Map::interval_type;
    Map m;
    m.add({Ival::closed(1,3), 10});
    m.add({Ival::closed(3,5), 6});
    m.add({Ival::closed(1,8), 9});
    m.add({Ival::closed(7,8), 15});

    for (auto e : m) std::cout << e.first << " -> " << e.second << "\n";

    std::cout << "------------------------------\n";

    for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(m.equal_range(Ival::closed(3,3))))
        std::cout << e.first << " -> " << e.second << "\n";
}
```

This will tell us:

```
[1,3) -> 19
[3,3] -> 25
(3,5] -> 15
(5,7) -> 9
[7,8] -> 24
------------------------------
[3,3] -> 25
```

Notice how

- the consolidation very accurately reflects that the *point* `[3,3]` is the only only point that coincided with both `[1,3]` and `[3,5]` from the input data simultaneously, and as a result, we get halfopen intervals in the combined set (`[1,3)`, `[3,3]` and `(3,5]`).
- Note also how the query for this one point *correctly* returns the sum of `10+6+9` for all the three intervals you were interested in.

### What Use Is This?

So, you see I shifted the focus of the question from the "How?" to the "What?". It usually helps to state the goal of code instead of the particular mechanics.

Of course, if instead of the sum you'd have been interested in the average, the minimum or the maximum, you'd likely find yourself writing some custom combining strategy.

**Bonus** In case you wanted, here's how you can at least write the solution to the problem posed in the OP using Boost Icl: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa9852fcfce0321)**. Though it's not particularly efficient, it's straight forward and robust.

Comment: the Coliru example is still `O(N)`, not `O(log N)`, or am I missing something? (I got to a similar solution that you showed, but it is a pity that Boost.ICL won't support a logarithmic solution).

Comment: @TemplateRex It appears to be O(1). No matter what stdin/command line arguments/environment I pass to the program, it takes equal amount of time for each input. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid a linear search from the start of the map, because if the first element is {0,INT_MAX} then it matches and the elements you want are not necessarily in a contiguous range, e.g. if you have {1,3},{2,2}{3,5} you only want the first and last elements when the key is 3.

You can stop searching when you reach an element with `first` greater than the key.

Something like this (untested):

```
typedef map< pair<int,int> , int > Map;

std::vector<Map::iterator>
find(int key, const Map& m)
{
  std::vector<Map::iterator> matches;
  for (Map::iterator it = m.begin(), end = m.end(); it != end && key <= it->first; ++it)
  {
    if (it.first >= key && key <= it.second)
      matches.push_back(it);
  }
  return matches;
}
```

You could turn it into a functor and use `find_if` but I'm not sure it's worth it.

If you just want one iterator returned per call:

```
typedef map< pair<int,int> , int > Map;

Map::iterator
find(int key, const Map& m, Map::iterator it)
{
  for (Map::iterator end = m.end(); it != end && key <= it->first; ++it)
  {
    if (it.first >= key && key <= it.second)
      return it;
  }
  return m.end();
}

Map::iterator
find(int key, const Map& m)
{ return find(key, m, m.begin()); }
```

Comment: I need log(N) time complexity similar to Print BST keys in the given range .

Comment: You can't get log(N). You have to start searching from the first element, and you have to check every element up to `m.lower_bound({key+1,0})`

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of iterators you could store (and use) corresponding keys of the map. If so then the code could look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> m;
    m[{ 1, 3}] = 10; 
    m[{ 3, 5}] = 6;
    m[{ 7, 8}] = 15;

    typedef std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>::value_type value_type;
    typedef std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>::key_type key_type;

    int search;

    auto in_range = [&search]( const value_type &value )
    {
        return value.first.first <= search && search <= value.first.second; 
    };

    search = 3;

    std::vector<key_type> v;
    v.reserve( std::count_if( m.begin(), m.end(), in_range ) );

    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        if ( in_range( p ) ) v.push_back( p.first );
    }

    for ( const auto &p : v ) 
    {
        std::cout << "[ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " ]" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
[ 1, 3 ]
[ 3, 5 ]
```

Take into account that it is supposed that key.first is less than or equal to key.second where key is the key of the map.

Comment: That works, but does two full passes over the map even if every element has `p.first > key`

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely  In this case at first you can use upper_bound that to find the first appropriate iterator.

Comment: There's no benefit to using `upper_bound`, since you have to start from the beginning anyway you might as well just do a linear search from the first element and stop when you reach the element that `upper_bound` would have returned ... finding that element in advance doesn't help much, it turns O(N) into O(n+log(N)) (where N = m.size() and n = distance(m.begin(), m.upper_bound(...))), but you can do it in O(n)

Comment: Why not use copy_if instead of the loop?  You used count_if for the count, seems reasonable to use copy_if for the copy.  Something like: `copy_if(begin(m), end(b), back_inserter(v), in_range)`

Answer (score 0):

if you only need an iterator to the next value found in the map, you can use the std::find_if algorithm like this:

```
int key=2;
map<pair<int,int>, int>::iterator it =std::find_if(m.begin(),m.end(),
                         [key](pair<pair<int,int>,int> entry)
                         {
                           return (entry.first.first <= key) 
                                  && (entry.first.second >= key);
                         }
                         );

cout << "the next value is: [" << it->first.first << "/";
cout << it->first.second << "] " << it->second << endl;
```